# change password link on login page

Tags: django, django-admin

I have default `/admin/login/`

and page and default `http://localhost:8000/password_reset`

I'd like a "forgot your password?" link on login page. Is there a straightforward way to do it or do should i just override the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add password reset url to the Django Admin login page, you have to override default template and provide your own. You will also have to make your own password reset templates, since django admin does not provide any by default.

django admin template can be found here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10.6/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html

Comment: My hole point is that there is https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_form.html. I was wondering how come those 2 are not linked.

Comment: In fact they don't include views with these templates in urls, but templates are still there, so you can use them together with the views. I guess, they didn't use it for security reasons. Usually django admin is for closed admin group and shouldn't be used for public registration, password reset etc. Yet I cannot find official info on that. :)

Comment: And password reset is done pretty well - with reset hash mailed to you (mail template is there too). I used it few times and like such a bootstrap.

Comment: you can use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-app-namespace-template-loader to overwrite  them easily.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is the default: for [1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-a-password-reset-feature) or [dev](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-a-password-reset-feature) (also available in the version that was available when you posted [1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-a-password-reset-feature)). No need to override any templates.